# Parsing one buffer affects another?

Tags: c

I am developing a history function for a custom C shell for a class.  I need the history to display the last twenty commands that have been entered in the shell.  The command history is being stored in a local text file with the following format:

```
0001 <command>
0002 <command>
0003 <command>
...
```

When I attempt to print lines from the history file, only the numbers are being printed and not the command itself.  Here is my function to print the history:

```
169 int print_history()
170 {
171     int first = (current - 20);
172     if (first < 1)
173         first = 1;
174
175     char **arg_p;
176     FILE *fp = fopen("history", "r");
177     int count = 0;
178     char buff[MAX_LENGTH];
179     while(fgets(buff, sizeof buff, fp) != NULL)
180     {
181         char *temp_buf = buff;
182         printf("%s\n", temp_buf);  // this line prints the entire line, just as I need it
183         arg_p = parse(buff);
184         printf("%s\n", temp_buf);  // this line prints only the number
185         int temp = atoi(arg_p[0]);
186         if(temp >= first && temp <= current)
187             printf("%s\n", temp_buf);
188     }
189     fclose(fp);
190 }
```

The printf lines with the comments (182 and 184) are just for error checking.  When I parse `buff`, it somehow changes `temp_buf` so that it does not display correctly.  The output from those two lines (for a single loop cycle) appears as follows:

```
0035 exit

0035
```

Here is my parse function that `buff` is being passed to:

```
76 char **parse(char *line)
77 {
78     int size = 64;
79     int position = 0;
80     char **words = malloc(size * sizeof(char*));
81     char *word;
82     word = strtok(line, DELIM);
83     while (word != NULL)
84     {
85         words[position] = word;
86         position++;
87         word = strtok(NULL, DELIM);
88     }
89     words[position] = NULL;
90     return words;
91 }
```

Any ideas on why parsing one buffer is affecting another buffer as well?  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: *" When I parse buff, it somehow changes temp_buf."* That is because they are the same buffer. `char *temp_buf = buff;`

Comment: So using `char *temp_buf = buff` ties the two buffers together so they will always equal each other?  I was assuming this line would create a second buffer that would remain unchanged when the first buffer was modified.  I believe I've fixed this by using `strcpy(temp_buf, buff)`.  Thank you!

Comment: There are not two buffers. There is one buffer, with two variables pointing to it. Lesson 1 with strings. `A = B` does not create a new string. And `strcpy(temp_buf, buff)` will not work unless memory has been allocated. As suggested, use `strdup`.

Comment: Gotcha.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `parse()` function, you are storing the word as

```
words[position] = word;
```

However, you should do

```
words[position] = strdup(word);
```

e.g duplicate the string. The contents of `word` aka `line` aka `buff` (from main) would change once you read the next line.

Comment: I made this change and have not noticed a difference in behavior.

Comment: @Unrealcow, that is because of `strtok` issue as it changes contents of `temp_buf` as suggested by @Leandros.

Answer (score 2):

`strtok` is destructive.

> This function is destructive: it writes the '\0' characters in the
>   elements of the string str. In particular, a string literal cannot be
>   used as the first argument of strtok.

Taken from the `strtok` doc [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok).

Comment: I did not realize that.  Is there another function you would suggest to keep this from happening?

Comment: `strtok` is generally not a good function, it's not thread safe, and destructive. My suggestion is to write you a string tokenizer on your own, it's not hard. It could leave the original string untouched, and create a copy of the token, instead of returning a part of the original string (like strtok does).